# PID controller for a very wide temperature range (∆T=190°C)

Tags: arduino, control-system, temperature, pid-controller, peltier

I'm designing temperature control system based on Peltier elements. And it's needed to work on a very wide temperature range - from below zero to more than 100°C. So there is two work modes - cooling and heating. I've implemented a PID controller, made different gains for two modes. And I can adjust them to go to a specific temperature (e.g. 100° or -5°) from room temperature (25°). But when I want to go e.g. from -5° to 60° it may go into oscillations or conversely grow very slowly. Should I break my large range in smaller subranges? Or maybe different gains depending on difference between current and target temperature (∆T)?

Also, I thought to implement auto tune algorithm, but I didn't found anything for the Arduino?

Comment: are you using a controller or making your own code? if making own code, linearize the output stage, that will ease your loop design a LOT. Heaters usually dump in a controlled amount of power, but for control purposes, you are concerned with rate-of-change of temperature, and that depends on T difference. Similar with peltier's --- so set it up so that the controller output is a value that is (to first order) linear vs dT/dt ... then have an output linearizer function translate that into a physical output based on the T diff's

Comment: sorry misspoke -- heat PUMPS or coolers will have that behavior, and it includes peltiers

Comment: I'm writing my own code. Do you mean move from PID controller and implement, for example, simple P controller?

Comment: Keep the controller, add an additional function in series with the signal that goes to the plant (the peltier). That function reduces the non-linearity of the plant, as seen from the controller. Keep it simple, you only need a partial improvement in linearity. If you can reduce the nonlinearity down by factor of 3 or so it'll make it much easier on the loop. I am making some assumptions here about what is really the root cause, but it's something that has worked well for me in similar situations.

Comment: My PID controller returns power in range from -100%(cooling) to 100%(heating). And I'm using H-bridge to control voltage on the Peltiers. So I have already implemented such  a function, that translates power to PWM

Comment: ok lets break it down... is power *input* to the peltier linear to *heat flow* output? Is the proportionality constant the same for all (T_hot - T_cold)? Is it the same in both directions?

Comment: Proportional gain is different for cold and hot, because it's harder for the system to cool down than to heat up. The power given on Peltier seems to be linear with the output heat

Comment: bingo! so if you haven't already done so, come up with a really, really simplified model for that. You'll have to make some assumptions about T_hot but that's ok -- doesn't have to be nearly perfect, the function has to have roughly the right shape (quadratic, 1/x, etc).

Comment: Great, thanks much. But I have one more question. Should my function be dependent on ∆T (for example going from 25° to 50° is the same as going from 75° to 100°) or on target temperature (going from 25° to 100° is the same as going from 75° to 100°)? I have a feeling that neither option is correct and it would be function of two variables: ∆T and T

Comment: Today I've tested the system and tried to find some kind of linearity. But the conclusion is that the function depends on both: Target temperature and ∆T. As 25°->100° behaves not the same as 0°->75° and 25°->100° behaves differently from 0°->100°.  So my plot would be not a curve but rather a surface.

Comment: no problem, that's normal. If the range of the "other" temperature is small, like 25C, just assume it is in the middle of the range for simplicity. If you have a sensor on that temperature, even better. Can you post the data?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the PID should be able to handle that requirement without having to break it down into subranges.

It can be tricky to find the right values for a PID.

Check the answer of [this post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-good-strategies-for-tuning-pid-loops) about the process of adjusting the PID, it's easier to go step by step rather than randomly changing the values.

More detail can be found [here.](https://pidexplained.com/how-to-tune-a-pid-controller/)